# Pricing (Single and Double) Window Barrier FX Options

Tags: option-pricing

recently I have been trying to understand how to price FX options with single and double window barriers.
Could someone please recommend a source (e.g., book, article, etc.), where I can find the pricing formulas.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A window barrier option is one where the barrier is monitored only during an interval starting after "today" and ending before the option matures. Closed form pricing formulas will

- (typically) only exist for the Black-Scholes model with constant volatility and further simplistic assumptions such as deterministic interest rates;
- (if they ever got published) be horrendously complex -even under the above simplistic assumptions.

For example, instead of the CDF of the one-dimensional normal distribution we are familiar with in full time barrier options, the true window barrier option will require the three dimensional normal CDF.

It is far better to apply a more realistic model and solve numerically for the price for example by Monte Carlo or a PDE method. See for example
[this paper](https://www.scirp.org/pdf/JMF20120400003_11331519.pdf).

In addition: a window barrier option will (as time passes) sooner or later become knocked out, or turn into an early ending partial time barrier option.

Black-Scholes formulas for those were published by Heynen and Kat and can be found in the book by

E.G. Haug, *The Complete Guide to Option Pricing Formulas*.

The [paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/file/index/docid/924247/filename/window_double_barrier_options_TGuillaume.pdf) by T. Guillaume that you found is quite good but seems to have a few typos:

- $\widetilde{\mu}$ and $\overline{\mu}$ should be flipped. In formula (1) the $\mu$ with the $+$ sign in front of $\sigma^2$ definitely belongs to the $S$ term which we know from the vanilla Black Scholes formula.
- The second exponential term in formula (2) should be
  $$
  e^{\frac{2\mu}{\sigma^2}(h_1-nh)}
  $$
  without a 2 infront of $nh\,.$

I wrote some Python code and matched the results in his table quite well.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Kurt G. I will look deep into the two sources you referred to. Thank you again!

Comment: I came across this [paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/file/index/docid/924247/filename/window_double_barrier_options_TGuillaume.pdf). Have you seen it? In general, I have a number of questions, but shortly – I am trying to compute the analytical values of SWDKOP from Table 1 on page 27 (of course using the Proposition 1 on pages 5-6). I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Thanks for that paper. I was not aware of it. Best to compare Guillaume's magnificent formulas to, say, a monte carlo simulation. Not because I have any doubts but I know from experience that many typos can occur.

Comment: I have tried a few different ways to implement the formula, but unfortunately I am not able to come to the results provided by the author. I get nonsense, i.e. negative values of the option price. Either I do not understand the formula correctly or there is a typo in the paper. I am stuck, but I will keep digging.
Anyway, thank you for the time! :)

Comment: The window barriers are outlined in section 4.17.4 Partial-Time Single-Asset Barrier Options from Haug’s “The Complete Guide to Option Pricing Formulas” (second edition, 2006), right?
It seems that the formulas are provided for call options only. Do you have any idea where I can find the corresponding put option formulas (regarding single window barrier)? Perhaps that would be a different source. That would be of great help. Thank you!

Comment: I do not have that newer edition of Haug's book. But I found a few typo's in Guillaume's [paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/file/index/docid/924247/filename/window_double_barrier_options_TGuillaume.pdf) that you found. Will post details.

Comment: Great, thank you! I think I also noticed a few points, e.g., in (1) $\bar{\mu}$ and $\tilde{\mu}$ need to be swapped; in (36) the limits of the integral should be also different? But I admit I haven't really dived too much into details.

Comment: (36) worked very well as Guillaume wrote it. Apparently when he created his table he did not have the typos I mentioned in his code. Otherwise his results would not match monte carlo and binomial tree.

Comment: It is just now that I saw you have updated your reply. Thank you so much for the help!
I also run the calculations using python, but unfortunately, I cannot get the results from the paper (even though I did the corrections you mention). Would you mind giving some hints about the python code?
The easiest way would be to post my code, but unfortunately it doesn’t fit the “Add a comment” box. And is not an answer, so I shouldn’t post it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you! If this is fine for you, I could send you my code by mail and you could have a look. I mean, it is simple, but apparently there is a mistake. I tried to send you a message, but I didn't find a way. I think I am not allowed to post my mail here.

Comment: I have just sent the message! Thank you!

Comment: I am trying to implement Guillaume's paper too but I am struggling to match his prices on page 27. Would you mind sending me a copy of your python code ? My email is lch0928@gmail.com. thanks. Dave

Comment: @DaveLui Please understand that I am not an open source host of python code. I don't even know if I still have that. Guillaume's typos in the formulas (not in his tables) are identified above in detail. From my experience the main difficulty with the implementation of such formulas is to have a good version of the CDF of the two-dimensional normal distribution.